# How to browse Wordpress links on a local network WAMP server

Tags: wordpress, wamp, local

I have read a post on this topic but I have an issue.
This is what I did:

- I have a WordPress site accessible locally using `http://localhost/mysite`
- I put my WAMP server online from WAMP options
- I disabled Windows firewall
- I created a limited network between my PC and my Android phone successfully
- I got the IPv4 address of my PC from network properties which is `192.168.42.219`
- I launched / accessed the website through my connected phone successfully with the address `http://192.168.42.219/my site`

But whenever I click on any link within the website, instead of opening

```
http://192.168.42.219/mysite/thepage
```

the address

```
http://localhost/mysite/thepage
```

shows in the address bar and

> Page not found

error displays.

If I type the address

```
http://192.168.42.219/mysite/contact
```

on the address bar and enter, it will open correctly

How do I browse the site perfectly with all the links working?

Comment: What code is creating the links? It appears it is using your hostname, you need to use the IP address.

Comment: Because your server name is set to 'localhost' all of the links are relative to 'localhost' which is on the machine you're browsing from, and will break.  You need to change your server name and reference it by name on the host that you're testing from.

Comment: WordPress stores the domain name you used when you installed it in its database, and will use that on all redirects. If you install it as `192.168.42.219/mysite` then it will work, or you must re-configure it [The WordPress Documentation for moving a site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: The site is a WordPress site.

Please I need a detail answer that will solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will try to honor the domain you define in the admin dashboard, so you must change it from there. You should be able to navigate using your IP address while in the dashboard without having the domain enforced.

In case you can't, you'll need to edit a certain record in the `wp_options` table, but that would be overkill if the first way works.

Comment: please I tried changing the WordPress URL and site URL from the dashboard but it did not work. 
please how can I do it successfully even if it means changing the wp_options.

Please I need a detailrd answer that will solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try to load an image from the url? If you can read static files from localhost then you might have mod_rewrite disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Open `wp-config.php` file within Wordpress root. at the beginning of the file, right after the batch documentation add these two lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://192.168.42.219/mysite');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://192.168.42.219/mysite');
```

changing `mysite` string to whatever your document root folder is under `C:\wamp\www`.

Depending on your situation, you may need to hit a **Save Changes** on Wordpress **Permalinks** submenu page, under **Settings** admin menu.

Note that the **homepage** link is not populated dynamically through `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL`, so you may change it manually into IPv4 version, thorough **Menus** submenu under **Appearance**

Comment: Oh,It worked perfectly Now.

Adding the 2 lines of code in wp-config.php PERFECTLY SOLVED ALL the problems. Thanks.